# HTML Parsing issue with BeautifulSoup Library

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am working with the BS library for HTML parsing. My task is to remove everything between the head tags. So if i have `<head> A lot of Crap! </head>` then the result should be `<head></head>`. This is the code for it

```
raw_html = "entire_web_document_as_string"
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)
head = soup.head
head.unwrap()
print(head)
```

And this works fine. But i want that  these changes should take place in the `raw_html` string that contains the entire html document. How do reflect these commands in the original string and not only in the `head` string? Can you share a code snippet for doing it?

Comment: use `tag.clear()` if you want to clear the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically asking **how to export a string of HTML from BS's `soup` object**.

You can do it this way:

```
# Python 2.7
modified_raw_html = unicode(soup)

# Python3
modified_raw_html = str(soup)
```

Comment: it is giving me error "Undefined Variable: unicode"

Comment: @hnvasa my mistake, I was thinking Python2. Answer updated for Python3.